# Consulta agrupación de botones - Xamarin/Android/C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, layout

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en donde en la parte superior tengo 3 botones cuya longitud abarca todo el dispositivo horizontalmente, a pesar de la longitud del texto.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
<Button Text="BOTON1"     Clicked="buton1" x:Name="Button_buton1" />
<Button Text="BOTON2"     Clicked="buton2"/>
<Button Text="BOTON3"     Clicked="buton3" />
```

Si lo pongo como vertical, me hace lo mismo, pero verticalmente, es decir, me abarca de arriba a abajo, y obviamente tampoco es lo que quiero.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
<Button Text="BOTON1"    Clicked="buton1" x:Name="Button_buton1" />
<Button Text="BOTON2"    Clicked="buton2"/>
<Button Text="BOTON3"    Clicked="buton3" />
```

Por otro lado, lo estoy queriendo cambiar, para en vez de poner texto como tal, usar un simple icono, y no logro ponerlo uno al lado del otro. Se puede controlar el ancho,alto?

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
<Button Image="icon.png"   Clicked="lkjklj" x:Name="Button_klkjlk" />
<Button Image="icon2.png"  Clicked="kllkj"/>
<Button Image="icon3.png"  Clicked="kklj" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo que quiero son esos iconos de forma horizontal en la parte superior, y obviamente más pequeños, y claramente le cambiaré la imagen como tal.

Y si hago estos cambios, ahora no me muestra los botones y a parte no veo de forma adecuada el campo para introducir un texto,

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="5">
<StackLayout Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="White" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start">
<Button Image="icon.png"  Clicked="Preferences" x:Name="Button_settings1" />
<Button Image="icon.png"  Clicked="Preferences" x:Name="Button_settings2" />
<Button Image="icon.png"  Clicked="Preferences" x:Name="Button_settings3" />
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
<Label Text="Nombre archivo:" />
<Entry x:Name="filename" Text=""/>
<forms:xxxxxx
x:Name="xxxx"
BackgroundColor="White"
WidthRequest="250"
HeightRequest="400"
/>
</StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Y por último, creo que se ve de forma evidente lo que se quiere. Debajo de los 3 iconos, pedir el archivo,  y debajo el otro control de de dibujo. Tampoco logrado con lo siguiente:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="5">
<StackLayout Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="White" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start">
<Button Image="icon.png"  Clicked="sdfsdf" x:Name="Button_settings1" />
<Button Image="icon.png"  Clicked="fdsfsd" x:Name="Button_settings2" />
<Button Image="icon.png"  Clicked="sdfsdf" x:Name="Button_settings3" />
<Label Text="Nombre archivo:" />
<Entry x:Name="filename" Text=""/>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
<Label Text="Nombre archivo:" />
<Entry x:Name="f2ilename" Text=""/>
<forms:dfsdf x:Name="sdfsdf"
BackgroundColor="White"
WidthRequest="250"
HeightRequest="400"
/>
</StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Gracias

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

No tengo muy claro lo que quieres, para revisarlo mejor deberías poner alguna captura de pantalla de lo que tienes y lo que quieres obtener, pero me temo que puede ayudar ver sobre el atributo HorizontalOptions de StackLayout 
Prueba algo así.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
  <Button Text="BOTON1" Clicked="buton1" x:Name="Button_buton1" />
```

Aquí tienes información sobre este atributo
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.View.HorizontalOptions/

Comment: Y si hago los siguientes cambios, no veo de forma adecuada, para introducir el campo de texto.

Answer (score 0):

men yo lo hice a si

```
Children ={
  mensage,                
  new StackLayout{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center,
    Children={
      botonSi,
      botonNo,
    },
  },
```

dentro de un children y si me pone los dos botones centrados uno junto al otro si alguien sabe como cuadrar  la posición respecto al eje y gracias